# Python Except Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Syntax error except python
I am new in python. and I trying to chatbox and this Syntax error appears

line 32
    except:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

(THIS IS MY CODE)

```
while True:
        try:

            audio = r.listen(s)
            speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')

            print('You:', speech)
            response = Bot.get_response(speech)
            print('EVA:', response)
            speack.Speak(response)

             except:
                 speak.Speak('Sorry')
```

Comment: Your code is totally invalid. Have you looked at any examples of `try/except`? Read a tutorial? Read a textbook? Read documentation?

Comment: How did you variable `speack` change to `speak` ?

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, it is required for indicating what block of code a statement belongs to. It will helpful to you if you start reading some basic tutorials first like `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/`. Fo try and except syntax you can here `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html`

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation for instead of {} in other languages, try to use same space before line starting for where you want make black.

and also use try before using expect:

```
print('You:', speech)
response = Bot.get_response(speech)
print('EVA:', response)
try:
    speack.Speak(response)
except:
    speak.Speak('Sorry')
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct indentation as below. Also, write the speak same in both try/except block.

```
while True:
    try:
        audio = r.listen(s)
        speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')
        print('You:', speech)
        response = Bot.get_response(speech)
        print('EVA:', response)
        speak.Speak(response)
   except:
        speak.Speak('Sorry')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect. Make sure they are aligned.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
print('You:', speech)
response = Bot.get_response(speech)
print('EVA:', response)
try:
    speack.Speak(response)
except:
    speak.Speak('Sorry')
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your try and except are **not** at the same level of indentation. Try to indent the code like below.

```
while True:
    try:
        audio = r.listen(s)
        speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')

        print('You:', speech)
        response = Bot.get_response(speech)
        print('EVA:', response)
        speack.Speak(response)

    except:
        speak.Speak('Sorry')
```